# Swift: Make Int Enum conform to Plottable protocol in order to show a legend using Swift Charts

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I am trying to make my Int enum conform to [Plottable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/plottable) in order to use a legend in my Swift Charts. I'm not sure if I've understood the way on how to implement it correctly. Here is how my enum:

```
enum Type: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Plottable {
      init?(primitivePlottable: Int) {
           self.init(rawValue: primitivePlottable)
    }

      var primitivePlottable: Int {
           return rawValue
    }

      var id: Int {
           return rawValue
    }

      case first = 32
      case second = 434

    }
}
```

My chart looks like this:

```
 Chart {
      if let allObejcts = object.objects(type: Type.first) {
           ForEach(allObejcts) { object in
                BarMark(
                     x: .value("#", object.indexInSegment),
                     y: .value("Distance", object.distance)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("type", object.type))
            }
        }
    }
.chartLegend(position: .bottom, spacing: 8)
.chartLegend(SwiftUI.Visibility.visible)
.chartForegroundStyleScale([
                    Type.first: Color.pink,
                    Type.second: Color.yellow
])
.frame(minHeight: 200)
```

[image: chart screenshot]
Despite compiling and running with no errors, the legends isn't visible. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation states for `enum` it should be `String` as raw type

[image]

so making next works (tested with Xcode 14b5 / iOS 16)

```
enum Type: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Plottable {
    init?(primitivePlottable: String) {
        self.init(rawValue: primitivePlottable)
    }
    
    var primitivePlottable: String {
        return rawValue
    }
    
    var id: String {
        return rawValue
    }
    
    case first = "32"
    case second = "434"
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so using String is the only way to use the enum as *categorical data*? If I cannot use Int, I have to change the database scheme and convert all stored values and it would also take more disk space to use String instead of Int.

Comment: Don't think it is required for data-base, you can convert it in init, from Int to String, and back where needed, but run-time enum should be String.

Comment: Thanks, I took a shortcut for now and made my own LegendView:
`struct ChartLegendDescriptionView: View {
    var color: Color
    var description: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle().fill()
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .frame(maxHeight: 8)
            Text(description)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}`